# review board diff not uploading

Tags: apache, unix, svn, review-board

i am currently attempting to do a diff using review board but keep getting an ambiguous error message:

```
Error uploading diff
Your review request still exists, but the diff is not attached.
```

The debug messages do not give much away either, no errors whatsoever....

```
>>> RBTools 0.4.1
>>> Home = /home/tom
>>> HTTP GETting api/
>>> HTTP GETting http://127.0.0.1/api/info/
>>> Using the new web API
Index: /trunk/0.1/scripts/configure-apache.sh
===================================================================
--- /trunk/0.1/scripts/configure-apache.sh  (revision 143)
+++ /trunk/0.1/scripts/configure-apache.sh  (working copy)
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
#! /bin/bash
-
+echo hello
cd ..
#SRCHEAD="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
SRCHEAD=$SRC_HEAD
```

This is what my ".reviewboardrc" file contains:

```
REVIEWBOARD_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/"
```

the repository path is: "https://XXX/svn/infinity/trunk/0.1"

does anyone know where i can start in order to resolve this issue i am seeing?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a workaround is to do a manual svn diff and save to a file and then compare the working copy with the trunk in the web ui

Comment: Well, that can be done using the IDE itself. This answer does not specifically solve the asked question.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you are facing may be that **the relative path in the diff file is not correlated with the path of the repository** as it is configured in Reviewboard.

Reviewboard, in order to find in the repository the files mentioned in the diff, will concatenate the URLs like this:

- URL of the repo as configured in Reviewboard
  +
- **optionally** - the Base directory as it appears in the
  [Reviewboard Upload diff dialog](http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/1.6/users/review-requests/uploading-diffs/) - which can be absolute/complete
  but also relative(!)
  +
- the relative path of the modified file as it appears in the diff file.

**All these must be correlated.**

Therefore, in your case, if your repository configured URL is:
`https://XXX/svn/infinity/trunk/0.1`
and your relative path in the diff file is:
`/trunk/0.1/scripts/configure-apache.sh`
... that will not work because the resulting absolute path of the file in the repo will be incorrect:
`https://XXX/svn/infinity/trunk/0.1/trunk/0.1/scripts/configure-apache.sh`
**Possible solutions would be:**
Your URL for SVN should be configured in Reviewboard like this:
`https://XXX/svn/infinity`
**OR**
The diff should be created at a lower level in the folders hierarchy - in this case it should be done at `../0.1/` level so that the path in the diff file results in `/scripts/configure-apache.sh`

HTH!