# reviewboard: post-review error uploading diff with basedir configuration error

Tags: upload, diff, review-board

I'm working in Ubuntu and I want to use post-review to create a new review request for reviewboard with a manually-generated .diff file but failed.

I worked on post-review for most time of today but find myself stuck on this postbasedir problem. I asked three of my colleagues to sit on my seat to solve this problem but they too found themselves run out of effective solutions.

here is the problem:

I set repoistory and reviewboard_url in the .reviewboardrc file, I'm sure the two settings are ok because the request was successfully created in review board and the repository points to the directory where the target file resides.

here is the content of .reviewboardrc:

============================= .reviewboardrc ===============================

```
REVIEWBOARD_URL = "http://10.22.200.166:8088"
REPOSITORY = "http://svn.d.xiaonei.com/wap/renren/renren-wap-talk/trunk"
```

============================================================================

I run post-review as follows but failed on uploading the Doxyfile.diff file and here is the content of it:

============================== Doxyfile.diff ================================

```
Index: Doxyfile
===================================================================
--- Doxyfile    (revision 107236)
+++ Doxyfile    (working copy)
@@ -1,3 +1,5 @@
+#POST_REVIEW_TEST
+POST_REVIEW_TEST =
 # Doxyfile 1.7.6
 # This file describes the settings to be used by the documentation system
 # doxygen (www.doxygen.org) for a project.
```

=============================================================================

and the output error message with debug info enabled

====================== err msg ===============================================

```
houchenxi@houchenxi-PC:~/renren-wap-talk$ post-review -dp --diff-filename=Doxyfile.diff 
>>> RBTools 0.4.2
>>> Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) 
[GCC 4.6.1]
>>> Running on Linux-3.0.0-22-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-11.10-oneiric
>>> Home = /home/houchenxi
>>> Current Directory = /home/houchenxi/renren-wap-talk
>>> Checking the repository type. Errors shown below are mostly harmless.
DEBUG:root:Checking for a CVS repository...
DEBUG:root:Checking for a ClearCase repository...
DEBUG:root:Checking for a Git repository...
DEBUG:root:Running: git rev-parse --git-dir
DEBUG:root:Command exited with rc 128: ['git', 'rev-parse', '--git-dir']
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent )
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
---
DEBUG:root:Checking for a Mercurial repository...
DEBUG:root:Running: hg showconfig
DEBUG:root:Running: hg root
DEBUG:root:Command exited with rc 255: ['hg', 'root']
abort: no repository found in '/home/houchenxi/renren-wap-talk' (.hg not found)!
---
DEBUG:root:Checking for a Perforce repository...
DEBUG:root:Checking for a Plastic repository...
DEBUG:root:Checking for a Subversion repository...
DEBUG:root:Running: svn info http://svn.d.xiaonei.com/wap/renren/renren-wap-talk/trunk
DEBUG:root:Running: diff --version
DEBUG:root:repository info: Path: http://svn.d.xiaonei.com/wap, Base path: /renren/renren-wap-talk/trunk, Supports changesets: False
>>> Finished checking the repository type.
>>> HTTP GETting api/
>>> HTTP GETting http://ourhost:8088/api/info/
>>> Using the new web API
>>> HTTP GETting http://ourhost:8088/api/repositories/
>>> Attempting to create review request on http://svn.d.xiaonei.com/wap/renren/renren-wap-talk/trunk for None
>>> HTTP POSTing to http://ourhost:8088/api/review-requests/: {'repository': 'http://svn.d.xiaonei.com/wap/renren/renren-wap-talk/trunk'}
>>> Review request created
>>> Uploading diff, size: 335
>>> HTTP POSTing to http://ourhost:8088/api/review-requests/130/diffs/: {'basedir': '/renren/renren-wap-talk/trunk'}
>>> Got API Error 207 (HTTP code 400): The file was not found in the repository
>>> Error data: {u'stat': u'fail', u'file': u'/renren/renren-wap-talk/trunk/Doxyfile', u'err': {u'msg': u'The file was not found in the repository', u'code': 207}, u'revision': u'107236'}

Error uploading diff

Your review request still exists, but the diff is not attached.
```

==========================================================================

In the err msg above we found that the basedir parameter {'basedir': '/renren/renren-wap-talk/trunk'} is incorrect, which is supposed to be the full path from "http",namely "http://svn.d.xiaonei.com/wap/renren/renren-wap-talk/trunk" , but no matter how we try to modify the .reviewboardrc or add command line arguments, we just cannot correct this value to the expected right value, we searched in the help info by running "post-review --help", but there just isn't the "--basedir" option available.

All I have to do is to correct the basedir value to the correct full path , either by modifying the .reviewboardrc or changing post-review arguments.

Does anyone have any similar experience for solving this problem, and suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem may be the correlation between the path of the SVN repository:
`http://svn.d.xiaonei.com/wap/renren/renren-wap-talk/trunk`
and the relative path in your diff file (the level at which it was generated in the hierarchy of folders):
`Index: Doxyfile`

Unless the file Doxyfile is situated directly in the trunk, you should try to re-create your diff at such a level so that the diff will contain the missing relative path between the trunk and Doxyfile:
`Index: /missing/path/to/Doxyfile`
..or to update your SVN URL in Reviewboard so that the URL contains itself the missing path.

You will find a detailed explanation of this correlation in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13214468/1790539) for the post: [review board diff not uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11345357/1790539)

HTH!